# How to use React Router's redirect function?

Tags: routes, reactjs, react-router

I want to configure React Router in the following way. If a certain route is matched the user is redirected to another one. [Documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/b06d1db7864ba16e36dc7bdae40e18ed86d23907/docs/Glossary.md#enterhook) states that it is possible, but doesn't provide the exact way to achieve that. Does anyone have insight on this?

```js
type EnterHook = (nextState: RouterState, replaceState: RedirectFunction, callback?: Function) => any;

type RedirectFunction = (state: ?LocationState, pathname: Pathname | Path, query: ?Query) => void;
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**EDIT** *See other answer for new, non-deprecated react-router syntax*

---

There's a good example of how to use the `onEnter` hook in the [auth-flow example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/efac1a8ff4c26d6b7379adf2ab903f1892276362/examples/auth-flow/app.js#L122). Here's the relevant code:

```js
function requireAuth(nextState, replaceState) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn())
    replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/login')
}

render((
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('example'))
```

As you can see, when the `/dashboard` route is accessed the `requireAuth` function is called. It receives two arguments: `nextState`, which is a [`RouterState`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/b06d1db7864ba16e36dc7bdae40e18ed86d23907/docs/Glossary.md#routerstate) object that represents the state the user is about to enter, and `replaceState`, a [`RedirectFunction`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/b06d1db7864ba16e36dc7bdae40e18ed86d23907/docs/Glossary.md#redirectfunction) that can be called to replace that state with something else. In this case, if the user isn't logged in, `requireAuth` calls `replaceState` like this:

```
replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/login')
```

The second argument is obviously the pathname the user will be redirected to. The very first argument is an object that can contain any data we want the route handler (in this case the `Login` component) to have. Here the pathname the user was trying to go to (`/dashboard`) is set as the `nextPathname` property so after logging in the user can be redirected to that page (see the `handleSubmit` method in the `Login` component).

If the user is logged in, `requireAuth` does nothing, and since `replaceState` is never called the route works as usual, which is to say the `Dashboard` component is rendered.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer!

Comment: I'm using universal rendering and unfortunately this method results in 302 redirects. Is there any way I would be able to use 301 redirects in case of a server request?

Comment: Could anyone tell me how nextState and replaceState have been injected as function arguments ?

Comment: @Bacem `requireAuth` is a normal function passed to the Route component as its `onEnter` prop. Route calls the function just like you’d call any event handler in your one React components, e.g. `this.props.onEnter(nextState, replaceState)`. (Also note that if you’re looking for information about _current_ versions of react-router, this answer is very old.)

Comment: It seems onEnter method is deprecated. Please let me know the alternatives.

Answer (score 16):

Heads up to anyone reading this question as of react-router 2.0.0, replaceState(state, pathname, query) is now deprecated. You must now use replace(location) with a location descriptor instead.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#link-to-onenter-and-isactive-use-location-descriptors

From their guide:

```
// v1.0.x
(nextState, replaceState) => replaceState(null, '/foo')
(nextState, replaceState) => replaceState(null, '/foo', { the: 'query' })

// v2.0.0
(nextState, replace) => replace('/foo')
(nextState, replace) => replace({ pathname: '/foo', query: { the: 'query' } })
```

Comment: Hi. When we use replace function, it doesn't retain store state on redirection. How can I do that? I mean, how to pass store state(along with action dispatchers) in next route

Comment: Hi @user3241111 I added an answer below that I hope helps clarify.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example of how to do this with `react-router` 2.0.0 (using `replace` instead of `replaceState`):

In *router.jsx*:

```js
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!userExists()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/signin',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}

export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="protectedRoute" component={Protected} onEnter={requireAuth} />
      <Route path="signin" component={SignIn} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

Then, inside `SignIn` component, you can redirect after a successful sign in like this:

```js
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

signInFunction({params}, (err, res) => {
  // Now in the sign in callback
  if (err)
    alert("Please try again")
  else {
    const location = this.props.location
    if (location.state && location.state.nextPathname) {
      browserHistory.push(location.state.nextPathname)
    } else {
      browserHistory.push('/')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are 2 things different from your example above and my scenario. 1st is my authentication is TOKEN based and NOT like redirecting him to a sign in form which is a route(not in my case) in the same application. 2nd case.. AT the moment where you're doing replace(pathname:'/signin'....) I already know whether my user is logged in, condition "if (userExists())" is ALWAYS TRUE since he is surely logged in.. I just want to replace to '/notFound' page but application state is getting lost on loading this route. I want to protect some components from logged in users.

Comment: My app is isomorphic, so problem coming is.. I sent my TOKEN for auth to other url along with 'return url' which authenticated the TOKEN and sends redirects back to ''return url'. so if I do "cb()", it redirects to the protected URL and also retains my UserDetails but if I used "replace('/notFound')" then it forget the state.. At the instance where i've to cb() or replace(..), server state already has userDetails which I want to pass down to 'notFound' route.